# Open Data about Open Data

Tags: data-request, metadata

What are good open data sources for open data?

[data.gov](http://www.data.gov/) is nice but limited to American open data.

**[datahub.io](http://datahub.io/)** is based on CKAN, it comes closes to what I have in mind and it has an API. There's also a list of [CKAN instances](http://ckan.org/instances).

Are there other, similar initiatives?

Comment: It seems like your question might be very similar to http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3516/where-can-i-find-a-taxonomy-of-open-data-sites

Comment: Definitely related, but a bit less precise.

Comment: @Skram : taxonomies are about classifying the sites ... I'd have said it's closer to : http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/266/263

Comment: I would agree with Skram and Joe, both these posts are good answers to this question

Comment: Just a note that Data.gov has a great deal of data that covers others countries, either posted on behalf of the United Nations, World Bank, or data gathered during scientific experiments globally (e.g., NASA satellite images).  (Note: I am the Evangelist for Data.gov.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure that a StackExchange site is the best way to organize the kind of information you're looking for. I actually think a Wikipedia category is more appropriate and, indeed, [one already exists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Open_data). The [CC-licensed data subcategory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Creative_Commons-licensed_databases) looks particularly useful and could be expanded.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @philshem I completely disagree with your flag. While I editorialize a bit, this does in fact provide a perfectly reasonable answer to the question considering the question is: "Where can I find a list of open data?" and my answer is: "The largest collection of open data in the world."

Comment: Was referring to your first sentence.

Comment: Wikipedia is open with an ok API, but its data is almost never structured nice enough to classify as "open data". If only this info was on Wikidata or dbpedia.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [opendata.arcgis.com/explore.json](http://opendata.arcgis.com/explore.json). It's a good source for open data that is (mostly) spatial. Soon there will be a master search to look through all these sites at [opendata.arcgis.com](http://opendata.arcgis.com). There will also be a showcase of individual sites you can link to from there.

Full disclosure: I'm a product engineer on the Esri Open Data team.

Comment: I don't think it's a big deal in this case but you should be careful to disclose that you work with ESRI when linking to resources by your own company/team. I think this is inline with the self promotion info at https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/behavior

Comment: Thanks Skram, will do in the future. I'm new to the community and stack exchange in general so I'd love to help out around here in the right way.

Comment: totally! Y'all are doing some interesting stuff over @ ESRI DC. I've met a few of your coworkers.

Answer (score 1):

http://opendata.stackexchange.com fits your requirements since:

- it is precisely about open data,
- it is open data itself (cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required).